# Facebook post count, like count, comment count, share count of page Graph api v2.8

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

[image]

I am very new in Graph api , I need to implement this function(above screen-sort).

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{object-id}/likes'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Not getting the total likes of page.
Please guide how to use this.

**Actually I am trying to get total no of posts, comments, likes, share.**

Comment: The field holding the number of users that like the page is `fan_count`. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

Comment: how can I get total like , comments , share , posts of my page ?

Comment: Go read the documentation, it tells you what fields and edges are available.

Comment: Can you provide one sample code for total posts of page through graph api v2.8?

Comment: There is no counter field for the total number of posts on a page. You would have to go through all posts (pagination), and count yourself. But that is likely to give other issues as well, with rate limits, the API not being to good on “historical” data, etc.

Comment: Someone please help me to get total no of post on facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

I try a lot finally success to get total posts.

```
try {
     $post_request=$fb->get("/{$page_id}/posts");
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage(); 
      exit;
    }




$total_post=array();
          $post_response=$post_request->getGraphEdge();
$response_array=$post_response->asArray();
                   $total_post=array_merge($total_post,$response_array);
              if($fb->next($post_response)){
              while($post_request=$fb->next($post_response)){

                  $post_response=$post_request;
                  $response_array=$post_response->asArray();
                  $total_post=array_merge($total_post,$response_array);
              }
                //echo "<pre>";  print_r($total_post);
          }


else {
              $total_post=$post_request->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
              // print_r($total_post);
          }
         $page_post_total= count($total_post);
```